# wsl installed package precedence over windows

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some software/tools already installed on my Windows 10, incl. Node.js, Git, etc. I am setting up my dev environment in WSL.

Should I install the same packages again under WSL even if I have them installed in Windows? I need to have those installed under Windows to be able to use other tools like Eclipse IDE. What are the adv and disadv of using interop? If I do have the same software on both, which installation takes precedence over which? At the moment, I have Node installed on both and I have `node` and `node.exe` available from WSL.

I want to avoid issues that may arise for e.g. by having slightly different version of a software (for e.g. Git) on each system, and maintaining separate configurations. For this reason, I think seamless integration between Windows and WSL is maybe better, but on the other hand, I want the WSL is be "self-contained" by having all dependencies installed under it, if that is of any value.

Answer (score 1):

What to use is case by case. For example git, it is better to use the Windows version if your code is in your C: drive, because the Windows version takes care of the line feeds. You can create an alias: `alias git=git.exe`.

Node, for example, it is better to use the Linux version and hide the Windows one. In WSL Windows programs take precedence. For example, if you have Node.js in Windows and WSL, the Windows one will take precedence. The safest way is to remove the Windows one from the path when you start WSL.

For example, to hide the Windows version of npm in WSL, put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
WIN_NPM_PATH="$(dirname "$(which npm)")"
WIN_C_PATH="$(wslpath 'C:\')"
if [[ "${WIN_NPM_PATH}" == "${WIN_C_PATH}"* ]]; then
  PATH=$(echo "${PATH}" | sed -e "s#${WIN_NPM_PATH}##")
fi
```

This code was taken from the Pengwin project: https://github.com/WhitewaterFoundry/pengwin-setup/blob/91e471be48736fe3f7aa92154e868b191e951b4e/pengwin-setup.d/nodejs.sh#L35

Hope it helps

Comment: I had to remove the backslashes before `$`s to make this work.

Comment: I use the "remove Windows path" option myself, but some folks may find it easier to disable WSL's propagation of Windows paths using `/etc/wsl.conf` (disable the `appendWindowsPath` option).  It's probably easier to add the Windows paths you *do* want in than to remove those that you *don't*.